# Getting headers property from WP_Theme object

Tags: themes, oop

Using `wp_get_theme` returns an object holding the properties of the current theme. The `headers` property contains any array of information I wish to access.

I can access the other properties using normal notation

```
wp_get_theme()->theme_root
```

When I try

```
wp_get_theme()->headers
```

I get `NULL`

How can I access the array within the `headers` property? Below is a `var_dump` of `wp_get_theme()`

```
object(WP_Theme)#381 (11) {
  ["theme_root":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  string(14) "/path/to/theme"
  ["headers":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "Site Name"
    ["ThemeURI"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Description"]=>
    string(11) "Description"
    ...
  }
  ["headers_sanitized":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  NULL`
  ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access the `$headers` property as it is a [private property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

> Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member

For that reason, you get `NULL` when you try to access the property with `wp_get_theme()->headers`. You need to make use of the magic `__get()` method of the class to get the info you are after.

Example: (*From the codex page, [`wp_get_theme()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme)*)

```
<?php
$my_theme = wp_get_theme();
echo $my_theme->get( 'TextDomain' );
echo $my_theme->get( 'ThemeURI' );
?>
```